# Eigenvectors of the square of the matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Given $A: n\times n$ matrix with eigenvector $w$ for eigenvalue $c$, does $B$, where $B^2 = A$ have $w$ as an eigenvector?

I.e, $A*w = B*B*w = c*w$.  Is $w$ an eigenvector of $b$ with eigenvalue $\sqrt{c}$?  I know that $A^2*w = A*A*w = A*c*w = c^2*w$ implies $A^2$ has eigenvector $w$.

Comment: As Crostul said in their answer, this isn't in general true. But it *is* true for positive definite matrices $A$ and $B$.

Answer (score 3):

No. An example is the real square matrix 
$$B=
\left[
\begin{matrix}0 &1 \\
-1 & 0
\end{matrix}
\right]$$

which has no real eigenvalues (its characteristic polynomial is $x^2+1$ which has no real roots). However, $B^2 = -1$, so it has $-1$ as an eigenvalue, and all vectors are eigenvectors.

Comment: I think you made a computation error. B has characteristic equation $x^2-1$ and eigenvalues $1$ and $-1$.

Comment: You are right! I will edit.

Comment: You have another mistake: now $B^2=-I$ with eigenvalue $-1$.

Answer (score 0):

Crostul's answer is correct but I would like to give some intuition about how this situation is possible. If a matrix $B$ rotates vectors by a right angle then it has no eigenvectors. However when this matrix is applied twice, it inverts all vectors so $-1$ is an eigenvalue.